# Grammar for expression language

Tags: javascript, expression, grammar

I want to build a parser that can parse such expressions:

- A=3
- A<5 OR B>C
- A=null OR (B=3 AND C=false)

And then build up Mongo query expression. If there is such library it would help me a lot. Meanwhile I started with writing my own parser. I found Ohm.js that looks easy and it has online editor. I was able to get there:

```
Query {
  exp = simpleExp | andExp | orExp
  simpleExp = identifierName operator literal
  andExp = simpleExp "AND" simpleExp
  orExp = simpleExp " OR " simpleExp
  identifierName = identifierStart identifierPart*
  identifierStart = letter
  identifierPart =  letter | digit
  nullLiteral = "null"
  booleanLiteral = ("true" | "false")
  decimalLiteral = digit*
  stringLiteral = "\"" digit* "\""
  literal = stringLiteral | decimalLiteral | booleanLiteral | nullLiteral
  operator = "=" | "<" | ">" | ">=" | "<="  
}
```

The online editor accepts trivial expressions (A=3) but it does not matches an AND/OR combined expressions. Where is my mistake? Btw I do not insist on this library, I can accept other [parsers](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-javascript/) as well.

Comment: "*but it does not match an AND/OR combined expression*" - that's because your `andExp` and `orExp` can only contain `simpleExp` as operands, not each other (or parenthesised expressions, which seems to be what you want).

Comment: This is work in progress. I was interrupted with A=2 AND B=3 which did not work. It should match andExp having two simpleExps, should not it? I do not understand your comment "not each other".

Comment: simpleExp must be the last option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things are preventing your `exp` rule from matching the input `A=2 AND B=3`.

To better understand these, it would be a good idea to read Ohm's documentation, such as it is; specifically, the [syntax reference](https://github.com/harc/ohm/blob/master/doc/syntax-reference.md).

First, the `exp` rule is a "lexical rule", in Ohm's terms, because its name starts with a lower-case letter. There's only a small difference between [syntactic and lexical rules](https://github.com/harc/ohm/blob/master/doc/syntax-reference.md#syntactic-lexical), but it's making all the difference here:

> The difference between lexical and syntactic rules is that syntactic rules implicitly skip whitespace characters.

Since none of your rules are syntactic, whitespace is not ignored. But it's not recognised either, except by the somewhat odd `" OR "` token. In particular, the space before the `AND` cannot be recognised by the grammar so the parse fails at that point.

So a first step is to change `simpleExp`, `andExp` and `orExp` to syntactic rules by renaming them `SimpleExp`, `AndExp` and `OrExp`, respectively. You can then change `" OR "` to `"OR"` if you want to.

The second problem is not so simple. To solve it, it would be useful to look at the model used in the Ohm [example arithmetic grammar](https://github.com/harc/ohm/blob/master/examples/math/index.html). (Remember that grammars just have to do with the organisation of symbols; what the symbol means is dealt with elsewhere. So a grammar for boolean expressions using operators `AND` and `OR` differs from a arithmeric grammar using operators `*` and `+` only in how the operators are spelled. The way that the arithmetic language syntax determines that `*` has precedence over `+` is exactly the same as the way a boolean grammar would specify that `AND` has precedence over `OR`. But that's not the way your grammar is organized.

In particular, you are falling foul of a key aspect of PEG parsers (like Ohm), which is also mentioned in the [Ohm documentation](https://github.com/harc/ohm/blob/master/doc/syntax-reference.md#alternation). Alternation (the `|` operator) in the PEG formalism is *ordered*: (*emphasis added*)

> ```
> expr1 | expr2
> ```
>
> Matches the expression `expr1`, and *if that does not succeed*, matches the expression `expr2`.

In other words, if `expr1` matches, `expr2` is never attempted.

With that in mind, consider the rule:

> `exp = simpleExp | andExp | orExp`

Since both `andExp` and `orExp` start with a `simpleExp`, there is no way either of them could be matched. In order for them to match, `simpleExp` would have to match, and if `simpleExp` matches, the alternation succeeds immediately without trying other alternatives. (Many PEG parsing systems use `/` as the name of the alternation operator rather than `|` used by context-free grammars, in order to avoid confusing the semantics of the two operators. But Ohm chose not to do that.)

In fact, Ohm's example grammar is not really ideal; it suffers from the usual problem with top-down parsing (shared by PEG parsing), which cannot handle left-recursive grammars. As a result, the language described by the example grammar makes multiplication and addition right-associative. For multiplication and addition, this isn't a problem; `(a*b)*c` is mathematically the same as `a*(b*c)`. But it would make a big difference to division and subtraction, since `(a-b)-c` is *not* the same as `a-(b-c)` (unless `c` is 0).

PEG grammars (and many top-down parser generators) compensate for this problem by allowing repetition operators in grammar rules. So it's quite possible that a better way of writing both grammars uses repetition:

```
Exp = AndExp ("OR" AndExp)*
AndExp = SimpleExp ("AND" SimpleExp)*
SimpleExp = identifierName operator literal | "(" Exp ")"
```

Comment: Hello. I have read the short manual at Ohm page first, looked at the numeric example and javascript grammar. Then I started from the bottom - define literals, simple expression, and expression and so on. My comment from yesterday night showed that I found an ordering issue and fixed it. Thank you for more background, I plan to continue later with an priority issues.

Comment: @leos: cool, good luck with it. I've never used Ohm and am unlikely to start, since I'm really not a fan of PEG. But other than that and despite its lack of documentation, it looks workable. And actually, the documentation was sufficient for me to find the answer to your question :-) There are other parserd in JS. Many people like Jison, although the maintenance is a bit come-by-chance. There's also [nearley](https://nearley.js.org/).

Comment: I liked its separation of code from rules and the web builder is cool as well, so I tried it first. I have written some bison code 15 years ago, so it would be my second choice.